# Services module to build a XML server to show on android app

Tags: android, xml, json, drupal, drupal-services

I am doing something which seems to be a rocket science till now.
I want to show the latest content of a Drupal website on an Android application.
I just don't want to show the RSS feeds, but I want to also show the proper nodes and
new users added so for that I would be needing a services module.

I have installed the services module but i still don't know how to use it.

I have done XML and JSON parsing, so I will be familiar with any of the server whichever is easy to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have got mine working now.
Atleast till system.connect still cant get node.get to work
For making an android application for drupal we must have XMLRPCclient library in our application and following is the code for system.connect :-

String url = "http://plumberc36.com/services/xmlrpc";
       // String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8888";
        XMLRPCClient server = new XMLRPCClient(url);
        try {
            HashMap response = (HashMap) server.call("system.connect");
            String session = ((String)response.get("sessid"));
            Log.d("Response","" +session);
                }catch{
                   }

if anybody knows how to node.get the XMLRPCclient then please share

Answer (score 1):

I saw someone do this for Beer related website. Here is the [showcase](http://drupal.org/node/659772) on Drupal.org. There are tons of links in that article for you to explore further. There was also a presentation from the creators of the Services module at a Drupal Con.

Edit: here is the presentation from [SF2010](http://sf2010.drupal.org/conference/sessions/drupal-web-services-platform-using-services-module).

Edit: Here is the [docs](http://drupal.org/node/109782) from the project page.

Comment: thanks man, m growing thru the documentation and presentation also but i dnt think presentation is just an overview....

Comment: @abhishek - as part of a project I am working on I have a working proof of concept for what you are asking for. Unfortunately, I can't just "give" it to you, but you are still welcomed to contact me and maybe we can find another arrangement. shushu.i@gmail.com